# Running Sublime Text Editor on Server

Tags: server, sublime-text

I have a question about running GUI apps on the ubuntu server, e.g. sublime.
Is it possible? since there is no Desktop installed on the server.

what I mean is that can I **install sublime** text from **package manager**, run **subl** command and the new document opens in **sublime with GUI**.

Comment: argh, we're not talking about ssh here, then my answer does not apply ...

Comment: @pLumo that's ok I use ssh for managing multiple servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to edit files on a remote server as if you were sitting in front of a remote server:

```
ssh -X user@remote.server
```

Then run SublimeText with subl command.

Notice the usage of -X flag in the ssh command.

You can also do both steps in a single go, like shown below:

```
ssh -X user@remote.server subl
```

On the remote server you must have X-server, to install a minimal X11 server use comand:

```
sudo apt install xorg
```

! A complete desktop environment, XFCE, is installed on the server where i tested.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using X11-forwarding if the server allows. On the client you start such a session using `ssh -X`.

Note, that you'll find a security note in `man ssh`:

> X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display through the forwarded connection. An attacker may then be able to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.